# Why are rxjs/Observable functions like range not available?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

My package.json has the rxjs dependency:

```
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
```

I have imported it in my typescript code.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
```

I'm expecting that I will be able to use functions like `range` on the Observable.  http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-range

But they are not showing up at all in the autocomplete.  If I add it anyways (just to check), it gives me an error: `Error TS2339: Property 'range' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'`.

```
let x = Observable.range(1,10);  // Error! range does not exist on Observable
let y = Observable.of([1,2,3]);  // this is ok.
```

What am I doing wrong or what have I misunderstood about this library?

p.s. I'm using it as part of an ionic2 project.

Comment: You might be having the same issue as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548924/missing-observable-methods-rxjs-5-0-0-beta-0). Try `import 'rxjs/operator/range'.

Comment: It looks to be so.  I was able to add some other operators.  But not range.  Cannot find module 'rxjs/operator/range'.  Tried import 'rxjs/add/operator/range', but the same error again.
Do we need to add other dependencies in package.json?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. I meant `import 'rxjs/add/observable/range'`. You can see the file tree [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/5.0.0-beta.6/src/observable). `add` will add a property to `Observable`. Without that, you'd be importing the function directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New to RxJS, range is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167740/new-to-rxjs-range-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

Note: Details can be seen here -> [Anguar RxJS - Observable - Range](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/range)
You can try this.

```
import { range } from 'rxjs';
```

and

```
let x = range(1, 100);
```

in Angular in your app.component.ts you can import it like

```
import { range } from 'rxjs';
```

and then use it like

```
constructor(){
    const observable: Rx.Observable<number> = range(0, 100);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Hy, my friend just import into "app.module.ts".

```js
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: Actually no, don't do that. Instead import just the parts you need.

Comment: Bloat alert! To save significant bundle space, do a precision import with `import 'rxjs/add/observable/...`. See the tree view [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/5.0.0-beta.0/src/add/operator) for the exact paths.

Comment: It is not the way to do it. please consider following the documentation. thanks